# Align two headings closer to each other using CSS

Tags: html, css, text-alignment

I have two lines that have space between them. Like the one below....

```
 <h2> Something Something <h2>



 <h4> Something here too </h4>
```

I want it to look like this:

```
 <h2> Something Something <h2>
 <h4> Something here too </h4>
```

The space is shown in the browser. I used the tags just to make it clear.

[image]

How to reduce the space within the orange rectangle ?

Comment: Can you show the css that's being used?

Comment: There is NO difference between any of your codes as per browser output.

Comment: I'm learning to use css. I will attach a picture of what I'm taking about in a min and also the CSS code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, ensure that `padding` and `margin` on your header elements is 0.

After that, you can adjust their `line-height` values to get the amount of space you like. Example: http://jsbin.com/afivoq/4/edit

Another option for you!  You can apply a negative `margin-top` on header elements which follow other header elements, like so:

```
h2 + h4 { margin-top: -20px; }
```

See the jsbin for updated example.

Answer (score 1):

I'd set all padding and margins to 0.

```
h4, h2 { padding:0; margin:0; }
```

This is an oversimplification of your code most likely but it'll get the job done.

Answer (score 1):

Add it in your css:

```
h2{
    margin-bottom: 10px; //something smaller
}
h4 {
    margin-top: 10px; //Whatever you like
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your second `<h2>` isn't a close tag `</h2>` so your adding an extra H2 element.  Also take a look at [this example](http://cssdesk.com/fv9fE) with Firebug installed.  Firebug has a feature [called Layout](https://getfirebug.com/layout) which will show you where the space is coming from:

[image]

Comment: It was closed in the IDE. Thanks for the heads-up.

Answer (score 1):

Resetting your margin and padding for the header tags like everyone else is saying is a great start. The best advice I can give someone who is learning CSS is to get chrome.

Right-click the element you want to change and hit "Inspect element." On the right hand side, you can alter the CSS on the fly. Then you can copy and paste the results into your application. Chrome also has the ability to save your CSS code.